# Android tablet (Samsung galaxy tab) - table messes up on orientation change

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have a simple table in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/FzSwP/3/

CSS

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.name {
    background: url("http://www.lexus.ca/images/footer/logo.gif") no-repeat right center transparent;
    padding-right: 40px;
    width: 20%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

When I view it on the Samsung Galaxy tab, on initial load, everything seems fine but once I start changing orientation, things gets weird. When changing to landscape, the display is all messed up, it looks like the text are overlapping. It looks like it is showing the previous orientation text and the current orientation text. As in the screen changed orientation/resized but the display on the screen did not fully update.

My tablet is android 4.0.4, using the stock browser.

I am not sure what it looks like in other android tablets because I don't have one handy.

Is there a way to correct this behavior? or can other people confirm that this is NOT happening on a different device? I am open to js/jquery solutions if any

Comment: I highly suggest downloading the Android SDK. It comes with an emulator, for which you can set the screen size so you can simulate different devices. Otherwise, +1 because I'm often having to deal with such situations myself - I even bought three different phones and two tablets (galaxy tabs, 7 and 10.1 inches) just so that I can test these things more easily.

Comment: It seems some of the css might be the issue, I tried removing all css for that fiddle and the orientation change seems to work but of course in my use, I can't just remove everything. The Samsung galaxy has given me all kinds of issues in creating a responsive website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering this here so if someone else run into the same thing can have an easier time

The issue is with the webkit browser(like the android stock browser) as it does not fully render the table. As my coworker explains: there is a redraw flag or something like that, and when you switch orientation this flag does not reset so it does not fully redraw perfectly. To solve this, simply hie the element and check it's height then show. Using jquery it is a very simple process

```
$('.element').hide().height();
$('.element').show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FzSwP/5/

Chaining it will most likely work as well, I am just putting it in 2 lines so it is easier to follow. I have seen this on desktop chrome as well when displaying tooltip and the same thing will fix the issue.